# postgresql内でyyyymmddHHMM形式の数字羅列をunixtime(epoch time)に変換して抽出したい

Tags: postgresql

postgresqlに関しての質問です。
時間を表すカラム内の値「202007101010」
このようにyyyymmddhhMM形式で刻まれた数値の文字列を
unixtime形式の値に変換して抽出したいと考えています。

https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.4/html/functions-datetime.html
こちらを参考にしているのですが参考になるフォーマットが見つかりません。

論理的に

1.文字型のyyyymmddhhmmの数値羅列を、timestampにキャスト
2.timestampをunixtimeにキャスト

でいけるかと思っているのですが、調べても使用例がなかなか出て来ませんので
解る方いましたらご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/12/html/functions-formatting.html)と[`extract`](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/12/html/functions-datetime.html)によるキャストを組み合わせることで目的を達成できそうです。

```
select extract(epoch from to_timestamp('202007101010', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'))
-- 取得できる値: 1594375800
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/392c7/2)